# What changes should I do in my code to exclude error 404 URL's from sitemap?

Tags: python, sitemap.xml, custom-error-pages

The code below creates the sitemap but it is including 404 error URL's. How do I exclude them from the sitemap?

```
from usp.tree import sitemap_tree_for_homepage
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import simplejson as json
from datetime import date

tree = sitemap_tree_for_homepage('')

root = ET.Element("urlset", xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")

for page in tree.all_pages():
    url = page.url
    prio = json.dumps(page.priority, use_decimal=True)
    # format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD see: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
    lm = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    cf = page.change_frequency.value
    urlel = ET.SubElement(root, "url")
    ET.SubElement(urlel, "loc").text = url
    ET.SubElement(urlel, "lastmod").text = lm
    ET.SubElement(urlel, "changefreq").text = cf
    ET.SubElement(urlel, "priority").text = prio

ET.indent(root, "  ") # pretty print
xmltree = ET.ElementTree(root)
xmltree.write("sitemap.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True )
```

Comment: What is _error URLs_?

Comment: you have to use `requests` or `urllib` to check if url gives status `404`

Comment: How to use urllib in this? @furas

Comment: similar to `requests` in answer below - you have to send request to this url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use (external module) [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or (built-in module) [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) to check if url gives status `404`

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/fake_url'  # wrong url
#url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'         # correct url

try:
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print('adding url:', url)
    # ... add `url` to sitemap ...
except urllib.error.HTTPError as ex:
    print('ex:', ex)
    print('wrong url:', url)
```

or

```
import requests

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/fake_url'
#url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'

response = requests.get(url)

#if response.status_code != 404:
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('adding url:', url)
    # ... add `url` to sitemap ...
else:
    print('wrong url:', url)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You could put it as function and return `True`/`False`

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

def is_correct_url(url):
    try:
       r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
       return True
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as ex:
       print('ex:', ex)
       return False

# ---

for page in tree.all_pages():
    url = page.url
    if is_correct_url(url):
        print('adding url:', url)
        # ... add `url` to sitemap ...
    else:
        print('wrong url:', url)
```

```
import requests

def is_correct_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    #return response.status_code != 404:
    return response.status_code == 200:

# ---

for page in tree.all_pages():
    url = page.url
    if is_correct_url(url):
        print('adding url:', url)
        # ... add `url` to sitemap ...
    else:
        print('wrong url:', url)
```

Answer (score 0):

This way only the non-broken links will be added

```
from usp.tree import sitemap_tree_for_homepage
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import simplejson as json
from datetime import date
import requests

tree = sitemap_tree_for_homepage('')

root = ET.Element("urlset", xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")

for page in tree.all_pages():
    url = page.url
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
       prio = json.dumps(page.priority, use_decimal=True)
       # format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD see: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
       lm = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
       cf = page.change_frequency.value
       urlel = ET.SubElement(root, "url")
       ET.SubElement(urlel, "loc").text = url
       ET.SubElement(urlel, "lastmod").text = lm
       ET.SubElement(urlel, "changefreq").text = cf
       ET.SubElement(urlel, "priority").text = prio

ET.indent(root, "  ") # pretty print
xmltree = ET.ElementTree(root)
xmltree.write("sitemap.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True )
```

Comment: @May what runtime error? You could show it in comment. Maybe you have to install `requests`.

Comment: @Furas I tried using urllib and requests. It is not displaying any specific issues, and it stops operating after crawling over certain urls.

Comment: @May maybe server blocks access because it thinks you are spamer/hacker. It may need to add some headers in requests to looks like read web browser. You may add `timeout` in requests to break connection if server will block it. Eventaully it may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser.

Comment: @May what was the response code when it stopped?.By looking at the response code you can tell if server is blocking it or not